# Prepend to a list causes error: value :: is not a member of Option[List[String]]

Tags: list, scala, prepend

`x` variable is an option list:

```
val x = Option(List("listX"))
```

Now trying to prepend something to list:

```
"listY"::x
```

causes error below:

```
error: value :: is not a member of Option[List[String]]
```

How can I prepend to an option list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because type of `x` is inferred from the value `Option(List("listX"))` is `Option[List[String]]` and you would like to prepend value in `List` inside `Option`, so instead you need to do: `x.map(value => "listY" :: value)`. Hope this helps!